# How to repeat a function by retouching the button

Tags: ios, swift, function

I'm working on Xcode7 with Swift 2.1
I have a problem with my code. I'm making a random function, When I touch the Button it automatically show you a Random movie.

But the problem is that I want it to repeat the function when I Retouch the button because when i retouch the button , nothing happen.

Here's the code :

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var random = arc4random_uniform(3)

@IBOutlet weak var NomDuFilm: UILabel!   
@IBOutlet weak var ImageFilm: UIImageView!  

@IBAction func ShowRandom(sender: AnyObject) {

    switch random {
      case 0:

        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "Inception.jpg")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Inception"          
        NomDuFilm.hidden = false

      case 1:       
        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "Memento.jpg")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Memento"    
        NomDuFilm.hidden = false

      case 2:
        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "ShutterIsland.jpg")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Shutter Island"
        NomDuFilm.hidden = false

      case 3:
        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "Prisoners.jpg")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Prisoners"
        NomDuFilm.hidden = false

      case 4:
        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "LePrestige.jpg")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Le Prestige"
        NomDuFilm.hidden = false

      default:
        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "PulpFiction.png")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Pulp Fiction"
        NomDuFilm.hidden = false

       }
```

Thank you for the help , and sorry for my approximative English...

Comment: please put your button click function.

Comment: It's the "ShowRandom" Action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add random call over the action call ?

```
@IBAction func ShowRandom(sender: AnyObject) {
   random = arc4random_uniform(3)

 //switch goes here.
}
```

Comment: The two answers gave you the solution, which is sort of unfortunate. This is a "give a man a fish" vs. "teach a man to fish" situation. I would have asked you to think it through, and try to reason out why it wasn't doing what you expected. Sometimes it takes much longer than you'd like to figure out what's going wrong. Learning to use the debugger and step through your code to watch what actually happens is a VERY good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are only initialising the `random` property once, when the instance is instantiated.  This means that each time `ShowRandom` is called, it will show the same image.

You can move the definition of `random` into the `ShowRandom` function and it will get a new value each time.

If you used arrays for your images and titles you could avoid the large switch statement.

Also, by convention your function name should start with a lower case letter (showRandom instead of ShowRandom)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var NomDuFilm: UILabel!   
@IBOutlet weak var ImageFilm: UIImageView!  

@IBAction func ShowRandom(sender: AnyObject) {

    let random = arc4random_uniform(4)

    switch random {
      case 0:

        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "Inception.jpg")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Inception"          

      case 1:       
        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "Memento.jpg")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Memento"    

      case 2:
        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "ShutterIsland.jpg")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Shutter Island"

      case 3:
        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "Prisoners.jpg")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Prisoners"

      case 4:
        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "LePrestige.jpg")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Le Prestige"

      default:
        self.ImageFilm.image = UIImage(named: "PulpFiction.png")
        NomDuFilm.text = "Pulp Fiction"

       }

       NomDuFilm.hidden = false
```